# MYSQL Join on meta key value?

Tags: mysql

I have very basic mysql knowledge (able to update and join tables) and am using phpMYAdmin but I am trying something just beyond my level now. I have looked at many other questions and answers but cannot find a solution for me. I am sure there is a very simple answer. This is what I am trying to do...

```
usermeta t1 looks like this:
user_id |  meta_key  | meta_value|
---------------------------------------
 1      |   mk1      |  value1  |
 2      |   mk2      |  value2  |
 3      |   desc     |  name    |
 4      |   mk4      |  value4  |
 5      |   desc     |  name    |
 6      |   mk6      |  value6  |
 7      |   mk7      |  value7  |
 8      |   desc     |  name    |
 9      |   mk9      |  value9  |
 10     |   desc     |  name    |

 userdata t2 looks like this:
 user_id  |   desc   |  
 ---------------------
 1        |   bob    |
 2        |   joe    |
 3        |   nancy  |
 4        |   jane   |
 5        |   lee    |
 6        |   jeff   |
 7        |   jill   |
 8        |   scott  |
 9        |   len    |
 10       |   carey  |
```

I want to update the t1 meta_value column in all the cells wtih the value "name", where the meta_key is "desc", with the data from t2.desc column, and joined where t1.user_id = t2.user_id, but I don't know how to do this! Does anyone have some mysql suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE usermeta t1
INNER JOIN userdata t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
SET t1.meta_value = t2.desc
WHERE t1.meta_key = 'desc' AND t1.meta_value = 'name'
```

You `INNER JOIN` both tables on `user_id`, and add a `WHERE` clause on which fields you want to update.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62c33/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Filipe! And thanks for the demo too. It looks like what I need but when I tried it returned "zero rows affected". I don't know why!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't ran it twice? and in the second time there was no one with meta_value = 'name'? Try doing a `SELECT * from usermeta WHERE meta_value='name';` to see if you get any rows back

Comment: I think you may be right about me running twice. I ran the SELECT statement from usermeta on the value and all rows were returned. How do I stop it from running twice? This is new (and exciting) terrain for me...

Comment: @user2591811. Running it twice was two clicks on the GO button. If you put your data back as it was and make sure you click only once, you should be good. The query i showed you wouldn't run it twice on it's own.

Comment: Strange then. I am only clicking the button once. I just tried again to make sure (I tried a few times) and it produced the same results of zero rows affected.

Comment: Don't know what might be happening then. Sorry. The query above should only execute once and update all the rows that have 'desc' as 'name'. Are you sure you have at least the data you showed on your question before executing?

Comment: OKay, Thank you for helping. Your sql looks great. I will keep trying on my end and report here when I understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I think you might have something very small that is making you get that "0 rows affected", but you can always make sure that this query happened by comparing the before and after. If this runs more than once because of "outside influence" :P, it doesn't turn your data invalid, on a second run it simply doesn't affect anything anymore.

Comment: I think I see the error of my ways. Will test and report back.

Comment: Yay! Your sql did the job. I made the silly error of using a data set in my "userdata t2" table that contained old user_id's. After I updated those your sql worked like a dream. Thank you!!!

Comment: @user2591811. Awesome :). If you feel this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how that works)

Comment: You certainly did answer my question! I was just marking it answered, and have done so now. Thank you again!!!